# Hibernate - Insert generated id in column other than id one on save

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

is there a way to perform insertion of an `@Id`-column value into a non `@Id` column when entity is being created/updated to avoid double-`save`-ing?

```
@Entity
class DummyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "dummy_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dummy_id_generator", sequenceName = "dummy_id_seq")
    Long id;

    Long rootId;
}

@Repository
class DummyEntityRepo implements JpaRepository<DummyEntity, Long> {}

@Service
class DummyEntityService {
    @Autowired
    DummyEntityRepo repo;

    void save(DummyEntityVO newDummyEntity) {
        var newEntity = newDummyEntity.mapToEntity();

        // !!! double save here !!!
        repo.save(newEntity);
        if(newEntity.getRootId() == null) {
            newEntity.setRootId(newEntity.getId());
            repo.save(newEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

What I was thinking was, since `@Id` is based on a sequence, I can try extracting next value from it and setting it as `id` and `rootId` before saving

```
Long nextId = // get next id somehow
newEntity.setId(newId);
if (newEntity.getRootId()) {
    newEntity.setRootId(nextId);
}
repo.save(newEntity);
```

However:

- I don't like perspective of interfering with Hibernate's id acquisition & saving methods
- I found package `org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer` but unfortunately there is no sequence based OOB incrementer for my DB so it would require a custom implementation (found something promising [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21425) though)

Comment: The save method returns the entity with the id. So get it from your first save call and use it from there on.

Comment: @michelson Could you explain why you need to duplicate id column?

Comment: @SternK project requirement, some kind of business rule.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `id` and `rootId` fields must be the same during insertion, however may differs during further updates ?

Comment: @eparvan yep, precisely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@GeneratorType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/GeneratorType.html) allows to generate/set values into entity during insertion phase. Suppose your entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
class DummyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "dummy_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dummy_id_generator", sequenceName = "dummy_id_seq")
    Long id;

    @GeneratorType(type = RecordIdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    Long rootId;
}
```

And your RecordIdGenerator class looks like:

```
public class RecordIdGenerator implements ValueGenerator<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long generateValue(Session session, Object owner) {
        return ((DummyEntity)owner).getId();
    }
}
```

Then when you'll insert new record hibernate will generate similar queries:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('dummy_id_seq')
Hibernate: insert into dummy (record_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

and record_id will be equal to id

Comment: this looks promising, I think it will suit my needs, thanks

Comment: In my case `id` is still `null` on the `generateValue` method.